# Observable periodically pause then continue

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

How to pause observable every 15 seconds then wait for 5s and then continue emitting? 
I made this example:

```
const digits = interval(1000);
const pauser$ = interval(20000).pipe(mapTo(true));
pauser$.subscribe(item =>
  console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} pause fired`)
);
const pauseStopper$ = pauser$.pipe(
  concatMap(_ => timer(5000)),
  tap(() => console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} pause stopped`)),
  mapTo(false)
);

const observable = merge(pauser$, pauseStopper$).pipe(
  startWith(false),
  switchMap(paused => (paused ? NEVER : digits))
);

observable.subscribe(
  item => console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()}: ${item}`),
  console.error,
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

After first pause cycle it behaves nearly close to what I need. Any ideas on how to make this more clear?
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g43kph?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: what do you mean by 'pause' exactly? should event emitted during a pause be dropped, or buffered and the re-emitted once the pause is over?

Comment: Just like in my example. I suppose events implicitly buffering in the process memory.

Comment: Is the answer provided fitting to you? Or do you have any questions? It's a pretty high effort to write detailed answers and I would like to have at least feedback if it worked.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I shouldn't make it work for my case and used another solution. Your example works but every pause/play cycle resubscribes to original observable so it emits     (1,2,3,4...1,2,3,4) instead of (1,2,3,4...5,6,7,8). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I created a [player](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pause-play-player) function that gets three params:

- source$: Your source observable that should be paused/played
- play$: Continues to emit your source$ observable
- pause$: Pauses your source$ observable

```
const player = <T>(source$: Observable<T>, play$: Observable<void>, pause$: Observable<void>): Observable<T> =>
  merge(
    play$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => of(source$))
    ),
    pause$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => of(NEVER))
    )
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(stream => stream)
  )
```

**This function currently throws an error as far as I can see. In the short time I have atm I could not fix the error. The error is caused by of(void 0) in the pause$ switchMap. Later I will try to fix this error. Forfeit the error the function works.**

You can now use a play$ and pause$ Observable to emit the play/pause:

```
const play$: Observable<void> = interval(20000).pipe(
  startWith(void 0),
  mapTo(void 0)
);

const pause$: Observable<void> = play$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => interval(15000).pipe(
    take(1)
  )),
  mapTo(void 0)
);


const player$ = player(source$, play$, pause$);
```

Does this solve your problem? If there are any issues with the solution let me know and I try to adapt.

Comment: I replaced `void 0` in `player` function to `NEVER` and it works, but pause lasts only 2 seconds. Is there a way to make it more?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz and the code sample with NEVER. From the console output I see, there is no more error and the log also lasts forever. So this should be a running solution.